# Any way to use Google Apps Script to print a Google Sheets worksheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing

I'm writing to ask if there's anyway of **using Google Apps Script in Google Sheets to allow it so when a user clicks a button it'll then bring up the print menu (Or print automatically is possible.)** I have looked all over the web and can't seem to find anything that helps me with my specific wishes, so just wanted closure or a resolution!

(I am also aware I can assign scripts to a drawing for the button, just want the script if there is anything!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you can interact with your local printer via google scripts. I think it may be possible to use google cloud print services- I would take a look at this article.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget

Comment: Am I able to use this within Google Sheets? Looking at that article it just seems to be talking about HTML code on a webpage. (Sorry i'm new to google scripts!)

Comment: I do think it's possible using html service - I am not 100% though https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Comment: I'll have a go! I appreciate the help, i'll mark this as the answer since I don't think i'm going to get another answer as promising as this.

Comment: Yeah, maybe a new question directly regarding google cloud print- Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

A workaround could consist of linking a desktop spreadsheet (e.g., Excel) to the Google sheet. Then set a desktop script to open it (auto syncing the data), and printing locally. But this does not answer the question of how to do it with Google script. :(